# how to avoid alphanumeric execution order in gradle

Tags: java, build, gradle, build.gradle

I have 5 subprojects in my modules directory, each having a **build.gradle**  file:

**modules :**

- aSubProject
- bSubProject
- cSubProject
- dSubProject
- eSubProject

and my **settings.gradle** includes all 5 projects, but project b is dependent on the build output jar of project e (say eSubProject.jar),

How can I avoid the alphanumeric execution order in Gradle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is to tell gradle how the projects are related to each other. In the dependencies of each project you can add a dependency to another subproject.

For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':eSubProject')
}
```

Gradle will make sure that the projects are compiled in the proper order.

Comment: That works but if eSubProject has nested structure say : eSubProject/subDir/subsubDir/build.gradle,then execution fails,                          i update dependencies {
    compile project(':eSubProject:subDir:subsubDir')
}     it says could not find eSubProject:subDir:subsubDir in project :cSubProject

Comment: that shouldn't matter. If the root `settings.gradle` references all the sub projects it should work no matter the subdirectories.

Comment: Can you show the `settings.gradle` for your project? If you reference to the same names as you referenced in the includes there it should work. Also this `project(...)` references work on the `name` field of the subproject. So if you overwrite this one, you have to use the name you applied.

Comment: Consider marking my answer as answer if it helped you. ;-)